# git diff during pre-commit hook results in Not a git repository

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I'm trying to build a pre-commit script in git.  In that script I plan on running tasks if a certain folder has changed.  To test, in my script I have

```
git diff --cached | grep -q "^my/folder"
```

This results in...

```
Not a git repository
To compare two paths outside a working tree:
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>
```

`pwd` says I'm in the correct directory and `$GIT_DIR` is `.git`.  I was lead to belive that `--cached` was the special sauce to get this working in a hook.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though GIT_DIR is set, I would still try a:

```
git --git-dir=/full/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/full/path/to/rpeo diff --cached |grep -q "^my/folder"
```

That way, you are sure the hook is executed where it is supposed to.

Comment: I tried that.  No change.  In the end forcibly unsetting `GIT_DIR` fixed it.

Comment: @Hounshell Did you make sure to pass the `--work-tree` option?  `--git-dir` will work, but you also need to pass `--work-tree`.

Comment: I just noticed that you had it in a different order.  I changed to that order and it seems to work fine.  It actually raises another issue though. My script calls a number of other scripts and they all need the directory arguments, which is too painful.  So ultimately your answer is right, but I'm not going use it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`unset GIT_DIR` cleared it up. I'm disappointed that `--git-dir` did not.

Comment: I ended up sticking with this approach because sub-scripts needed to do it as well.  Because the script runs in a subshell I'm comfortable with this.