# git environment vs precommit hook

Tags: git, shell, npm

I have an angular web project.  I am trying to run a shell script as a precommit hook for git.

Here is the script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "finding ESLint..."

ESLINT="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/cf-itr-ui/node_modules/.bin/eslint"

# make sure eslint is installed:
if [[ ! -x "$ESLINT" ]]; then
    echo -e "\t\033[41mESLint doesn't seem to be installed, or I can't find it :(\033[0m "
    exit 1
fi

echo "ESLint found!"

for f in $(git diff --name-only | grep -E '\.(js|jsx)$')
do
    echo "linting '$f'..."
    git show ":$f" | "$ESLINT" --stdin --stdin-filename "$f"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "ESLint failed on staged file '$f'. Please check your code and try again. You can run ESLint manually via npm run eslint."
        exit 1 # exit with failure status
    fi
done
```

Running this script by hand in a terminal - everything works as expected.  Simple enough, right?  Hold on - it's about to get weird.

When executed as a git hook, the script runs, because I see it looking for and finding eslint, but the for loop does.....nothing.  So it just publishes the commit - no linting at all.

Had another developer clone the entire repo.  Same result.  Script runs fine by hand, finds files and lints them.  Run as a hook?  Find eslint, but lints nothing.  Had a 3rd developer try it - cloned the repo into a new directory, and his version works fine BOTH as a hook and by hand.

I am trying to find some difference in git env/config vars between us 3 but so far no luck.

If I run the git diff --name-only command from anywhere in the project tree - I DO see changes, so I don't think it's a mere path problem.

So it's like the hook has a different "shell" it's executing in, so it's not getting the same result from commands?  I don't know.  I'm well into mere spitballing at this point.  Anyone ever see this?

Before anyone asks:  all 3 devs are on Macs.  Only difference I have found so far:

The dev from whom this works is on git version 2.8.1.
The two non-working devs are on 2.10.2

Was there some change wrt how hooks are handles between 2.8 and 2.10?

TIA

Comment: The main trick to debugging Git hooks is figuring out how to observe them. In this case the hook runs on the same computer (vs pre-receive, update, and post-receive hooks, which *don't*). Being on the same computer helps a lot as most of the usual debug tricks work straight out of the box. Set the `-x` flag so that the shell writes each command to stderr as it executes it, for instance. Try the `-e` flag so that any command that returns a nonzero exit status causes the script to exit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

As in "[git diff during pre-commit hook results in Not a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20435928/6309)", you need to make sure GIT_DIR is unset.

```
unset GIT_DIR
```

(at the beginning of the script)

Comment: This does not work, nor does anything suggested in the linked answer.  :(

Comment: @MonkRocker What is the output of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` when the script runs as a hook? (both from the failed workstation and the one working fine). Is there any environment variable set on one workstation and not on the other?

Comment: On the failed workstation:  Fatal:  .git is not a repository.  On the working one - it returns the correct path.  I have no GIT_ env vars set at all.

Comment: @MonkRocker can you display `env` in both workstations to see if there are any difference between evnironment variables?