# `git diff` does not work when run from a git pre-commit hook

Tags: git, githooks

I have a git pre-commit hook that does some style checking on any modified files before committing.

The implementation is irrelevant, but it starts by calling `git diff`. Here's what i have in `(repo)/.git/hooks/pre-commit`.

```bash
#!/bin/sh


echo "=== Running script..."
git diff
echo "=== Done running script..."

# Other stuf
# ....

# Always exit with 1 so pre-commit hook always fails.
# Useful for testing
exit 1
```

When I actually try committing something, the `pre-commit` hook correctly fires, but the `git diff` command doesn't output anything (there are definitely modified files)

```
> git commit --all -m "foo"
=== Running script...
=== Done running script...
```

However if I run the `pre-commit` hook script directly/manually, it *does* work

```
> ./.git/hooks/pre-commit
=== Running script...
(... outputs git diff ...)
=== Done running script...
```

What's different about git calling the hook versus me manually calling it? It runs as the same user either way (my username)

I've also tried suggestions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435593/git-diff-during-pre-commit-hook-results-in-not-a-git-repository#20435742), but `unset GIT_DIR`, `--git-dir=`, and `work-tree=` didn't fix anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `git diff --cached` because the changes are already staged.

Comment: That did do the trick, but for my own curiosity - why does it work when i run `git diff` manually without `--cached` ? The changes aren't staged yet, as I have yet to run `git add` on anything (which is why when committing i ran `git commit --all`)

Comment: That's exactly why. `git diff` shows the diff between working directory and index. `git diff --cached` shows the diff between the index (staged) and HEAD. So, when you run manually without staging, you use `git diff`, and when you run `git commit -a`, you're staging first, so you need to compare the index with the HEAD, not the working directory.

Answer (score 5):

As [ishegg said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45721815/1256452), you will need `git diff --cached` here, but that's not necessarily the whole story.

There are two traps to be wary of here.  The first is what `git diff` does: it compares two *trees* (or tree-like things).  The second has to do with the very phrase *the index*.

#### The index, and selecting trees for `git diff`

Quite often, the two trees you diff are the trees associated with two specific commits:

```
git diff <hash1> <hash2>
```

(or the same with `<hash1>..<hash2>`, which—unlike most Git commands—*doesn't* treat the two hashes the way the two-dot `..` operation is described in [the SPECIFYING RANGES section of the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_ranges)).

It's also pretty common to have one of the two trees be your *work-tree*, which is what happens when you run:

```
git diff HEAD
```

for instance: this compares the commit named by `HEAD`—i.e., the current branch-tip commit—to the current work-tree.

Using:

```
git diff --cached
```

tells Git to compare the `HEAD` commit to the tree represented by your *index*.  Git's index, also called the *staging area* or the *cache*, is where Git builds up the *next* commit to make.  It's why you must run `git add` before committing: the `git add` command copies files from the work-tree to the index.

Using:

```
git diff
```

with no arguments at all chooses the index as the first tree, and the work-tree as the second tree.  Once everything has been copied from the work-tree into the index, this particular diff will be empty, which is what you are seeing here.

#### *The* index vs *an* index

The second trap lies in the fact that you are using `git commit --all`.

While Git talks about *the* index, and there is in fact one particular, distinguished index to go with each work-tree, Git actually allows for more than one index, using exactly one at a time.

When you use `git commit --all` or pass file names to `git commit`, Git makes a *temporary* index that it uses during the pre-committing process.  To indicate that there is a temporary index in play, Git sets the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE`.  This temporary index gets used instead of the ordinary index, up until either the commit is allowed and committed, or until the commit is rejected.

If the commit is rejected, Git just removes the temporary index, and everything goes back to the way it was before.  If things were not `git add`-ed, they are still not `git add`-ed.

If the commit is *accepted*, the temporary index *becomes* the "real" or "main" index, more or less.  Here things can get complicated, because you can stage some items in the real index, run `git commit --all` or `git commit --include <paths>` or `git commit --only <paths>`, and if the commit succeeds, the difference between the initial (main or real) index and the temporary index matters.

If you plan to do special tricks with files in the work-tree and/or their copies in the index, you may want to simply reject any attempt to work with a temporary index, so as to avoid these complications.  However, that will preclude the use of `--all`.

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful to know the distinction and how it works! Appreciate the insight, will avoid using `--all` where possible

Comment: But then it looks like git diff --cached does not use the temporary index indicated by GIT_INDEX_FILE.  How do I get the diff between HEAD and the index indicated by GIT_INDEX_FILE ?

Comment: @Droopycom: as long as the variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE` points to the correct path name, `git diff` should use it. There might be issues with relative path names here, perhaps setting `GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(realpath $GIT_INDEX_FILE)` would help in that case.

Comment: My bad, another  bug in my pre-commit script made it looks like git commit -a did not work as expected. But it does.